# Fix Chrome Size to Match Chromium Size

Tags: google-chrome

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04. I use both Chrome and Chromium. Chrome recently updated and the size is all out of whack (maybe the resolution changed?). How can I restore Chrome to match Chromium? See the picture below showing the smaller tab size for Chromium vs. Chrome.

[image]